# Github api get last Users that committed

Tags: github, github-api

I want to get the last users exe. last 100 users that committed on github regardless of repo.  I've looked around the github api but can't find the specific api call.

Comment: So you want to know the last 100 commits that happened globally over the entirety of GitHub?  I don't think there is an API for this.  Define what you are trying to do more clearly.

Comment: Exactly what you said, the lastest 100 commits that happened globally over the entirety of Github :).  I did find a way of first, finding the most recent updated Repos and then finding the last updated commit inside the repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Github Events API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-public-events) and filter [`PushEvent`](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) :

https://api.github.com/events?per_page=100

#### User(s) who have made the last 100 commits on Github

As a `PushEvent` may have multiple commits, you will have to sum the `size` for each `PushEvent` until you reach 100. Note that you also need to exclude `PushEvent` with 0 commit. You will also have to manage pagination as you can request 100 events max at once (if one request is not enough to get 100 commits).

An example using nodeJS :

```javascript
var request = require("request");

const maxCommit = 100;
const accessToken = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN';

function doRequest(page){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request({
          url: 'https://api.github.com/events?per_page=100&page=' + page,
          headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Some-App',
            'Authorization': 'Token ' + accessToken
          }
        }, function (err, response, body) {
          if (!err) {
            resolve(body);
          } else {
            reject(err);
          }
        });
    })
}

async function getEvents() {
    var commitCount = 0;
    var page = 1;
    var users = [];

    while (commitCount < maxCommit) {
        var body = await doRequest(page);
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        var pushEvents = data.filter(it => it.type == 'PushEvent' && it.payload.size > 0);
        commitCount += pushEvents.reduce((it1, it2) =>  it1 + it2.payload.size, 0);
        users = users.concat(pushEvents.map(event => ({ 
            login: event.actor.login, 
            commitCount: event.payload.size
        })));
        page++;
    }
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        count += users[i].commitCount;
        if (count >= maxCommit){
            users = users.slice(0, i + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(users);
}

getEvents();
```

#### Last 100 Users who have pushed commits on Github

The only things that changes is that we only check that `size` field is > 0 and build a map for distinct user.

An example using nodeJS :

```javascript
var request = require("request");

const maxUser = 100;
const accessToken = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN';

function doRequest(page){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request({
          url: 'https://api.github.com/events?per_page=100&page=' + page,
          headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Some-App',
            'Authorization': 'Token ' + accessToken
          }
        }, function (err, response, body) {
          if (!err) {
            resolve(body);
          } else {
            reject(err);
          }
        });
    })
}

async function getEvents() {
    var page = 1;
    var users = {};

    while (Object.keys(users).length < maxUser) {
        var body = await doRequest(page);
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        var pushEvents = data.filter(it => it.type == 'PushEvent' && it.payload.size > 0);
        for (var i = 0; i < pushEvents.length; i++) {
            users[pushEvents[i].actor.login] = pushEvents[i].payload.size;
            if (Object.keys(users).length == maxUser) { 
                break;
            }
        }
        page++;
    }
    console.log(users);
}

getEvents();
```